# Restaurant serves everything with money back guarantee, patron defeats them by ordering a Twinkie

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

I'd like to find a short short story, probably only one page long.  I've read it on the internet in English less than two years ago, probably [around 2018-08-04 when I was binging short short stories](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1037/2018/8/4).

The story tells that there's a very expensive restaurant where you have to put reservations months in advance.  The specialty of the restaurant is that they serve *everything*.  They have a money-back guarantee for this: if a patron orders something that they can't serve, then the entire three course meal is free for them.

The story tells about the protagonist dining in this restaurant.  The protagonist goes alone, and they may be a businessman, but I'm not sure in this latter.  Their orders for the first two courses are difficult, but the restaurant does serve them.  One of the courses is made of a rare animal, perhaps some kind of turtle or shark or whale.  The other course is made from an extinct animal.  The restaurant appears to be used to these extravagant orders, and the waiter serves them smiling and with compliments on the excellent choices.  I believe they have a group of recreated living animals very close to the extinct animal by selective breading, which is how they can serve the meat; there's no time travel involved.

As the third course, the protagonist orders a Twinkie, or some similar commercially branded dessert item.  The waiter returns, distraugh, and apologizes saying something like “our chef insists that we cannot, in good conscience, serve non-food items”, with the effect that they consider the branded dessert to have such bad quality that it doesn't even count as food.  The protagonist does not have to pay for the dinner, and, I believe, the waiter offers them to choose a different dessert.

I think the story is written in the third person, and there isn't more story than what I told, so no other characters have a role, but the descriptions and dialogs are more detailed than what I give.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

["An Indelible Feast"](http://www.stupefyingstoriesshowcase.com/0131115/0131115-10.html) by Alex Shvartsman.

> “My sincere apologies, but the chef is unable to fill your order. The man was indignant. He insists,” Alfred sighed, “that he cannot, in good consciousness, serve items that aren’t food in this establishment. We have a reputation to uphold.
>
> “Please make another selection. Your meal will, of course, be complimentary.”